# Add column based on contents of another column

Tags: r

**MY PROBLEM**
My `data.frame` is 174,792 obs. of 2 variables. I wish to locate a character string within a column then based on the contents, insert a new column that contains the respective character string.
 If I use the `iris` dataset...

**AN EXAMPLE**
`Species <- c("Setosa","Versicolor","Virginica")`
`Position <- c("Yard","Garden","Wild")`
I would like to iterate over the `Species`  column and for each specie, create a column to the immediate right that contains that specie's designated `Position`. For example, my data set would now look like:
**`data.frame(iris)`**
**`Species, Position`**
`Setosa, Yard`
`Versicolour, Garden`
`Setosa, Yard`
`Virginica, Wild`
**WHAT I HAVE ATTEMPTED**
I have tried `iris$Position <- ifelse(grepl("Setosa", iris$Species, ignore.case = T), "Yard"`and repeating the `grepl` statement by substituting each `Specie` and their `Position` although R returned me with the following error...
  `Error: unexpected symbol in: "`
Where am I going wrong **AND/ OR** is there a neater code than the above?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect for a named vector, though for it to work on the built-in `iris` data set, you'll need to match the case, so I've made your species vector all lower-case (since this method doesn't have an `ignore.case` argument):

```
Species <- c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")
Position <- c("Yard","Garden","Wild")

named.pos = Position
names(named.pos) = Species
iris$position = named.pos[iris$Species]
```

As for your error, it's a syntax error which means you missed a `"` somewhere, but in principle your idea would also work just fine. It's a bit overkill, since `grepl` is made to search within strings. Since you're matching the *entire* string, you can just use `==`, something like

```
iris$position = ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", "Yard",  
                       ifelse(iris$Species == "versicolor", "Garden", "Wild"))
```

Comment: The named vector worked perfectly! Thank you. When I matched for the entire string using `==` I did encounter an error that stated `unused arguments` so unsure what happened there...

Comment: Sounds like another syntax error. Make sure your parentheses and quotes are all matched, and that you have all the right commas. The `ifelse` line I have runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
levels(iris$Species)
#[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

As the `levels` of "Species" are in the same order as the replacement vector ("Position"), you could use `factor` and specify the `labels` as "Position".

```
iris1 <- transform(iris, position=as.character(factor(Species, 
                            labels=Position)))
```